# How to retrieve a picasa photo using Google api in Python

Tags: python, google-api, picasa

I am trying to retrieve a photo (the .jpg file) from a Picasa album using the gdata Google API. However I did not find any method which does it, even though it is possible to upload a photo using methods like InsertPhoto and InsertPhotoSimple.

I guess I must be missing something :-(. A simple example would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client API provides methods only for obtaining information on photos: http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#Photos

To retrieve an image, use an HTTP GET with information previously obtained. Read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingCached).

For this purpose you may use a Python library:

- [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)
- [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html)